# Why can't I have multiple a 1:N and a 1:1 one-way reference to a class in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm trying to set up multiple classes that reference a class, and they only need to be one way.

I have these classes:

```
class Widget
  include Mongoid::Document

  ...

class Template
  include Mongoid::Document 

  has_and_belongs_to_many :widgets, inverse_of: nil
  ...


class EntryText
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_one :widget, inverse_of: nil
  ...
```

When I try something like:

```
 EntryText.new.widget = Widget.first
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `=' for #<Widget:
```

I am able to change Entry Text to have this reference to Widget:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :widgets, inverse_of: nil
```

But since it will only have one widget, this is kind of an ugly workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `has_one :widget`, you should use `belogs_to :widget, inverse_of: nil`. Mongoid(also active record) stores id on the `belongs_to` side. So if the relation needs to be persisted only on one side, it has to be `belongs_to` otherwise we cannot get back from db the association which we tried to store.